# Manipulate Http response by Aop

Tags: java, http, spring-aop

I try to use AOP to wrap of the Http response. I have the following code:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ControllerResponse {
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* hu.example.app.kafkaexample.controller.Controller.*(..))", returning = "entity")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> logMethodCall(JoinPoint jp, Object entity) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Inside of the aop");
        ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity(entity, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I can get the log record on console, but the api call are not manipulated by the setting I did. My question is: can I manipulate the response type by aop? If yes, why is my code bad?

Comment: If you have no evidence, don't state something which is not true. I do read docs and sample codes. Next time avoid this kind of communication...
Anyway, @Around worked, thanks for that!

Comment: I did not mean to insult you, just to state the obvious. If you did in fact read the documentation, where did you find any example of an `@After` advice returning anything? And why did you not find `@Around`, which does exactly what you want? Your basic question _"can I manipulate the response type by aop?"_ is answered [there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice): _"The value returned by the around advice is the return value seen by the caller of the method."_

Comment: You stated "I never read documentation or any sample code", which is a lie. I wouldn't accomplish even this code if I didn't check any sample code. When I was referring your communication style I was thinking this. But I admit, I was superficial when I read about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on *kriegaex* comment, using `@Around` instead of `@AfterReturning` is the approach which allows to manipulate the response. I tried and worked for me.